# constpar in lme in R

Tags: r, lme4

Is there a function in the lme4 library (like constpar in mixed logit package) that allows me to set a parameter result to 0?

For example, if i have the following linear mixed effects model:

```
trips ~ (var1) + (var2) + (1+var3|season)
```

And my var3 is "Snow Fall". I would like to set the parameter equal to 0 during the summer season. Is that possible?

Thank you

Comment: Why wouldn't you create a separate variable that is 0 for that season?

Comment: No snow falls in the Summer time. Thus i would like to set that parameter equal to zero. You might ask: "why isnt it zero anyway?".  The answer lies in the fact that weather data is not perfect.

Comment: I repeat, why not do this in the data: `df[ df$season==0, "var3"] <- 0`. Working on the formula as the source of correcting data errors seems wrongheaded.